# Getting error in crontab @reboot

Tags: networking, bash, scripts, cron

I am trying to change my MAC address every time I reboot the system. So I wrote a script and it is attached bellow.

```
#!/bin/bash -x  
echo "Date $(date)"  
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service  
ip addr  
macchanger -r wlx9cefd5fe0d41  
systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

When I run the script in the terminal it's successfully changeing the MAC address but when I use crontab to do it I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Device or resource busy.
```

I am running the crontab as a root and by logs which I attached shows that the interface is down.
Can some one help me? If there is a better way I am open for it.

This is my crontab line:

```
@reboot bash -x /home/user/changeMac.sh >> /home/user/testlog.txt 2>&1
```

The log file:

```
++ date
+ echo 'Date Wed Aug 22 21:27:32 PDT 2018'
Date Wed Aug 22 21:27:32 PDT 2018
+ systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
+ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
  inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/ether  brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlx9cefd5fe0d41: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/ether  brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
+ macchanger -r wlx9cefd5fe0d41
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Device or resource busy
Current MAC:    (unknown)
Permanent MAC:  (unknown)
+ systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log doesn’t say that the interface is down, it complains it’s up! In order to bring it down properly, add

```
ip link set wlx9cefd5fe0d41 down
```

to your script before the `macchanger` line. To bring it up again afterwards, use the equivalent:

```
ip link set wlx9cefd5fe0d41 up
```

As you probably figured, for manipulating network devices `ip` should be used. NetworkManager is just a daemon managing the networking configuration.